# Convergence of the ratio of two infinite series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm currently working through problems given in *Mathematical Methods for Physicists* by Arken et al. I'm having a bit of trouble resolving a problem that comes up in Chapter 1. It is as follows:

---

If $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = K$, a constant with $0 < K < \infty$, show that $\sum_{n}b_n$ converges or diverges with $\sum a_n$.

*Provided Hint:* If $\sum a_n$ converges, rescale $b_n$ to $b_n' = \frac{b_n}{2K}$. If $\sum a_n$ diverges, rescale to $b_n'' = \frac{2b_n}{K}$.

---

Plugging everything in, I'm left with the following expression:
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = K \longrightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{b_n'}{a_n} = \frac{1}{2} \\
$$

From here, I would usually proceed to split the limit and rearrange like so:
$$
\frac{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n'}{\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n} = \frac{1}{2} \\
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}b_n' = \frac{1}{2} \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n
$$

In this case, I realise I can't do that because of the fact that under the assumption that $\sum a_n $ converges, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n$ must be equal to zero by the limit test.

Where have I messed up on my reasoning?

Thanks!

Comment: Since $K>0$, then there is an $N$ such that for $n>N$ we have $2K>a_n/b_n>K/2>0$. Therefore, $a_n,b_n$ have the same sign for $n$ large. By multiplying both by $-1$ if necessary we can assume that they are $\geq0$. If $a_n$ converges, then $\frac{2}{K}a_n>b_n$. Therefore $\infty>\frac{2}{K}\sum_{n>N}a_n\leq \sum_{n>N}b_n$. If $b_n$ converges, then use the other inequality: $2K b_n>a_n$.

Comment: @arugula The step from $a_n,b_n$ have the same sign for $n$ large to assuming $a_n\geq 0$, $b_n\geq 0$ for $n>N$ is invalid.

Comment: @Malcolm Let me teach you what you should have said. "@arugula I don't understand the step in which from $a_n,b_n$ having the same sign for large $n$ one can reduce the problem to assuming $a_n,b_n\geq0$." That is what you should have said. In that case I would have explained to you why it works. But since you didn't, then all you are getting is: You better study for your exams!

Comment: @argula Thanks for your advice.  $a_n = 10\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, $b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$  And you are correct, I don't understand how you can reduce a problem that is potentially about conditionally convergent series to one about absolutely convergent series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposition is incorrect as stated.

If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are series with positive terms then the result

Given
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n} = K\text{ with }0 < K < \infty
$$
implies that
$$\sum b_n \text{ converges or diverges with } \sum a_n
$$
is well known as the *Limit Comparison Test* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) has a proof).

If you leave out the assumption that $a_n,\ b_n > 0$  then there are counter-examples to the conclusion.  From Nguyen S. Hoang's *[A Limit Comparison Test for General Series](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.9.893?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)*:

If $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $b_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n}$
then $\frac{b_n}{a_n} \rightarrow 1$ and $\sum a_n$ converges as an alternating series, but $\sum b_n$ diverges.

Comment: Well known by all but myself it seems :P Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @isentr0pic Sorry, that is "well-known" in the mathematical sense, which is not necessarily the same as usual English usage ;-).  What I meant by that comment was that you could find more information by searching under the name Limit Comparison Test.  I wasn't trying to imply anything else.